# Why do Eclipse plugin IHandler APIs return false by default?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugins and was able to use the following links to create an Eclipse plugin that makes a contribution to the default text editor.

- [Eclipse Menu Contributions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions)
- [Eclipse Commands tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/)
- [Eclipse Official Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fcommands%2FIHandler.html)

The plugin works fine, but I have two questions regarding the `IHandler` interface. For a long time I realized that my plugin handler was not called. Then I saw that by default the `isEnabled()` returns false. After I enabled it to true, I saw that the handler is called only once. Then I saw the `isHandled()` is set to false. Setting both to true solved all my problems.

So my questions is:

Why do both these APIs by default return false? (It seems strange to me that the plugin developer would want to have it default false.)

I tried understanding their descriptions in the official documentation, but still I don't get why this should return false by default.

Is there something I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you have a multi page editor, you might have multiple tabs.

Each tab may have different actions. In that case, you may want the handler associated with that tab only to return true and false for other tabs.

Similarly for explorer you might want not all nodes to enable actions. For example, only clicking of a file should enable some action, not on a clicking of folder.

So to do selective enabling, isEnabled() returns false by default. You can provide your own logic to enable or disable.

Comment: thanks it makes sense to me . Its good to know about this behavior :-) Cheers